# How can I use Express to handle a request for specific route in a React Router app?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I'm making an app using React Router with an Express server. As is, the server only responds to requests to the root endpoint, and React Router handles navigation from there. But I'd like to be able to handle requests to say `myapp.com/user/a_cool_user_id`, instead of just to `myapp.com`. How can I instruct my Express server to simultaneously serve the app and navigate to that particular route?

I'm at a loss for how to proceed. I'm thinking that my server needs to just serve the same app, but then in the response I'm not sure how to *also* tell React Router to navigate appropriately.

**Edit:** In case it clarifies things: I'm hoping for this to work when the client is not yet at my webpage. (More specifically, I'd ultimately like to generate a QR code that takes the client to the `myapp.com/user/a_cool_user_id` route.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing this. I can give the client a URI including a query parameter, say `myapp.com?user=a_cool_user_id`. Then, inside of my React Router app, I check for the `user` query parameter, and if it exists, execute the function `navigate('/user/a_cool_user_id')` (using the `useNavigate` hook).

Answer (score 1):

This is a hello world example using express:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The code above expose an endpoint on the root, exactly as your case (myapp.com)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id
  const user = // Implement your code for retriving a user here
  res.send(user)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This second piece of code exposes one endpoint at the root (myapp.com) and another one on /user/a_cool_user_id (myapp.com/user/a_cool_user_id)

Comment: Thank for this response! However, I think this is missing the meat of my question. My question is essentially: How do I modify your lines `const user = ...` and `res.send(user)` response in such a way that I: (1) serve to the client my React Router app, and (2) automatically navigate them to the route `myapp.com/user/a_cool_user_id`?

Comment: In case it clarifies things: I'm hoping for this to work when the client is not yet at my webpage. (More specifically, I'd ultimately like to generate a QR code that takes the client to the `myapp.com/user/a_cool_user_id` route.)